# How do I redirect from example.com to apps.facebook.com/example?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-apps

Please see this image:

http://www.theatrenetwork.com/theatrenetwork-on-fb.png

Instead of my users seeing theatrenetwork.com, I want them to see apps.facebook.com/theatrenetwork.

I have asked a number of people how to redirect without looping, but people just offer terrible alternatives.

I can easily redirect from theatrenetwork.com to apps.facebook.com/theatrenetwork, but obviously the website simply continues to redirect and there's simply a blank facebook shell.

I expect that I need an index.html file or a .htaccess file that says 'REDIRECT TO APPS.FACEBOOK.COM/THEATRENETWORK ONCE ONLY' in coder language - something I cannot write.

I cannot code.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I redirect once only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383083/how-do-i-redirect-once-only)

Comment: And note that the question @Charles referenced is by the same user less than a day before this one.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend then is changing how your structure is set up. Make your domain point to index2.html which is an exact copy of your index.html but contains a redirect to your apps.facebook page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=http://apps.facebook.com/theatrenetwork">
```

Comment: Because facebook apps that contain websites ARE the websites. Look at theatrenetwork.com, then look at apps.facebook.com/theatrenetwork. This question is really very basic. I have been bombarded with questions for days about this. All the information is here, as simple as I can make it.  I have included counter arguments to the types of time wasting questions people keep asking over and over again. Please make sure you understand my question before asking more questions.

Comment: 60 people on this website have failed to figure this out but attempted  to answer it. I've had to reword it. Can nobody tell me how this can be done? I know ten workarounds, but I'm looking for a clean logical solution. Does nobody on this website know how to code from scratch? There's nothing to find on the internet about this, so therefore coders can't solve it? Please be a hero and actually calculate how to redirect once only.

Comment: It would just redirect to index2.html when it got there and keep looping.

Comment: all i need is for the index.html file to say 'only redirect if the url is theatrenetwork.com'. If it is not, don't redirect.

Comment: Okay then what you do is do my method but change your link in your facebook app to be index.html. So theatrenetwork.com/index.html

Comment: Link? There won't be any link. If this is not already clear from the image, the users will NEVER see the website - they will ONLY ever see the app. There is no link. A link would be easy. As you can see, both theatrenetwork.com and apps.facebook.com/theatrenetwork work perfectly.

Comment: The canvas url. Change it.